# How anonymous are ratings/reviews in the Android Market?

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

I can see from reviews other people have given to apps in the market that at the very least your account name is made public. However, I was wondering:

1. Is that the only thing made public?
2. If I only give a star rating to an app (but no comment/review), is this anonymous?
3. Is there any way to leave anonymous review comments (i.e. without visibly associating your account name with it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your device name is also made public. But, it can be faked easily.
2. As Play Store doesn't display who has starred, you'd be anonymous if you give star rating only. But, nothing can be said for future. I believe, Google stores this data and it can be made public based on TOS and PP we accepted in the beginning.
3. No. Currently, there's no way to leave review comments anonymously.

Comment: Note that the app developers can still see information about the country, device, mobile service provider and android version.

Answer (score 3):

A star rating without a review/comment is anonymous.  I don't think reviews/comments can be anonymous.

Comment: Note that the app developers can still see information about the country, device, mobile service provider and android version.